# New Padre on Fedora

Tags: perl, cpan, padre, cpanm

When I try to install Padre with cpan (or cpanm)...

```
bash-4.2$ sudo cpan Padre
...
CPAN.pm: Building P/PL/PLAVEN/Padre-1.00.tar.gz
Found locale    ru_RU.UTF-8
Found wxWidgets 2.8.12
Found Wx.pm     0.9921
Unparsable version '6,59' for prerequisite ExtUtils::MakeMaker at inc/Module/Install/Makefile.pm line 352.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
unexpected end of string while parsing JSON string, at character offset 281 (before "},"build_requires":{...") at /usr/local/share/perl5/CPAN/Meta/Converter.pm line 45.
at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/ExtUtils/MM_Any.pm line 831.
ERROR from evaluation of /root/.local/share/.cpan/build/Padre-1.00-UsByhx/winxs/Makefile.PL: unexpected end of string while parsing JSON string, at character offset 78 (before "}") at /usr/local/share/perl5/CPAN/Meta/Converter.pm line 45.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
PLAVEN/Padre-1.00.tar.gz
/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
```

This bug we have a few years. I can't find JSON, that was a reason of this error. Anybody pass this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are known problems in some releases of JSON::PP which cause problems further up the toolchain like this.

Try upgrading JSON::PP. If the toolchain issues prevent you from installing JSON::PP in the normal way, then download the [latest version of the module](http://api.metacpan.org/source/MAKAMAKA/JSON-PP-2.27300/lib/JSON/PP.pm) from CPAN, and manually replace the `JSON/PP.pm` file on your system.

Comment: bash-4.2$ perl -e 'use JSON::PP; print $JSON::PP::VERSION . "\n"'
    2.27300

Upgraded. -> Same problem ):

Comment: I wonder if CPAN is seeing the correct version of JSON::PP (you might have multiple copies on your system). You could try hacking CPAN::Meta::Converter to do `use Data::Dumper;warn Dumper(\%INC);` just before the place it fails to see what modules have been loaded from what paths.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora currently has Padre 0.90 available as a pre-built package. So you can install it with

```
$ sudo yum install perl-Padre
```

Comment: perl-Padre-0.90-10.fc20.noarch

TOO OLD